# MCMC algorithm -- understanding some paremeters

Tags: python, data, data-analysis, monte-carlo

I am trying to understand an MCMC program. I manage to run it, but I am trying to understand the meaning of the some parameters in the analysis.

The code is something like this

```
#Nsamples
nsamp   = 50000

#Burn-in
skip    = 300

#temperature at which to sample
temp    = 2

#Gelman-Rubin for convergence
GRstop  = 0.01

#every number of steps check the GR-criteria
checkGR = 500

#1 if single cpu , otherwise is giving by the nproc-> mpi -np #
chainno = 0
```

This is for the  `metropolis-hastings` algorithm.

How my results depend on these parameters or what these parameters mean ?

I understood the `nsamp` and `skip`, I also kind of know what `GRstop` and `checkGR` means but I have no idea what `temp` and `chainno` means. How does changing these parameters can effect the analysis ?